# Entity doubts - following Contoso University Tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity

I've been following the contoso university tutorial on Microsoft´s site and I have some doubts about how the Entity Framework is doing some stuff. Here we go...

On the beginning of the tutorial, we created three classes that will be turned into tables in my database.

I´d like to know when and how entity instantiates my classes to populate the objects.

Im using code-first approach.

Example:

The classes im using:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

After following the tutorial I can now list all my `Students` and theirs respectives `Course`(s), as well as their properties in enrollments lists.

When did entity instantiated my `Student` classes and populated it with the respective `Enrollment`(s) lists?

How does it know what enrollments are linked to that student?
I dont see any new constructor() ever beeing called.

This might be simple but Im kinda lost here.

Thanks

Comment: if you have a property with the following format in your class SomeOtherClassID EF makes this a foreign key. So In the Enrollments class CourseID and StudentID are foreign keys to the Student and Course table. The ICollection  is used to portray a One to Many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't instantiate anything ahead of time, and it doesn't have to. And there won't be anything in the table representing the virtual property as such, either.

These virtual properties are used by EF at runtime to store navigation information, and the collections can be null or contain 0 or more elements.  There's no magic, it's just by design that EF "new"s up the collection when it needs to.

If you want to be explicit about it, you can create a constructor on your POCO as well and set your collection equal to a new hashtable.